# Sort multidimensional array by value not sorting correctly

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array by date ASC but i'm having troubles with... so i would like to ask you guys and girls why this happens?

my code is (Run at: [Codepad example](http://codepad.org/FCRb3pJL) ):

```
$data = array (
          array (
            'date' => '2016-03-11 12:10:17',
            'type' => '1'
          ),
          array (
            'date' => '2016-03-12 07:16:25',
            'type' => '1'
          ),
          array (
            'date' => '2016-03-12 07:18:07',
            'type' => '2'
          ),
          array (
            'date' => '2016-03-09 14:57:42',
            'type' => '2'
          ),
          array (
            'date' => '2016-02-22 10:39:39',
            'type' => '1'
          )
    );
    usort($data, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
    });
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($data);
```

The issue is that the sorting is not good, i mean it need to be from February to March and is not doing this and i can't find why.

Any help is very appreciated !.

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you have any errors? What have you tried to fix it? Please read and follow the instructions on this page to produce a high-quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use the sort from the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare strings, not number, so you have unexpected results.

To compare two strings, you can use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

```
usort( $data, function( $a, $b ) {
    return strcmp( $a['date'], $b['date'] );
});
```

[`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns < 0 if first arg is less than second; > 0 if first arg is greater than second, and 0 if they are equal.